# C# Templates and Unintended/Unexpected Inference

Tags: c#, generics

I am working with a bunch of legacy web services and trying to come up with a streamlined approach to wrapping calls and checking the custom error types that may be returned.  I think I am close but C# infers a different meaning from what I intended and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am hoping someone can point out my mistake:

I have added a simple interface to the client proxy of each of the legacy services and created an extension method for calling methods and looking at the responses (each service has its own error types but all boil down to a number and a message).

```
    public static ApiResult<TModel,TResult> Call<TService,TResult,TModel>(this TService service, Func<TService,TResult> apiCall, TModel model) 
            where TService: ILegacyService 
            where TModel: BaseModel
    {
        ApiResult<TModel, TResult> result = default(ApiResult<TModel, TResult>);

        try
        {
            TResult apiResult = apiCall(service);
            /* extract/normalize custom, non-exception error types */
            result = new ApiResult<TModel, TResult>(model, apiResult, normalizedErrors);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = new ApiResult<TModel, TResult>(model, default(TResult), exception: ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Where the ApiResult type is like:

```
public class ApiResult<TModel,TResult>
{
    public ApiResult(TModel model, TResult response, 
            NormalizedErrorCollection errorList = null, Exception exception = null) { ... }
}
```

My hope is to then have a chain of checks for specific errors much like a  series of catch blocks that can assign human-friendly messages to an error model in BaseModel, e.g.

```
serviceInstance.Call(s => s.SomeMethod("Foo", 42), modelInstance)
    .On<ServiceCode>(ServiceCode.MaxQty, m => m.Message = "No more for you")
    .On<ServiceCode>(ServiceCode.NoID, m => m.Message = "Parent is gone")
    .On<Exception>((m,e) => m.Message = "Unexpected error")
    .Success((m,r) => m.Result = r.Result)
```

My problem is right at the top which the helper method which infers a meaning I did not intend:

```
CartService.Call(s => s.AddToCart(request.storeId, lineItem), model);
```

C#/VS state that the < Method Response Type > cannot be used as type parameter TModel and that there is no conversion between < Method Response Type > and BaseModel.

I cannot seem to figure out why the return type from the apiCall TResult is inferred to be the model type.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  (Finding specific answers to template questions is equally difficult so I apologize if this matches an existing answer, but I did try and search first).

Comment: What happens if you specify the generic arguments to `serviceInstance.Call`?

Comment: Can you include the exact error(s) you are getting, instead of paraphrasing it?

Comment: Same error if I specify the arguments: CartService.Call<ICartService,CartInfoResponse,AddToCartResponse>

Actual error message: CS0311 The type '....AddToCartResponse' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'ShopMRExtensions.Call<TService, TResult, TModel>(TService, Func<TService, TResult>, TModel)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '....AddToCartResponse' to '....BaseModel'.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of your code?  What is the declaration of `CartInfoResponse` and `AddToCartResponse`?  Based on the names alone, I expected `AddToCartResponse` to be the `TResult` parameter.  And neither of those look like model types.  Again, providing exact error(s) is preferred.  Better yet, update the original post instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for that! ... that was the problem.  AddToCartResponse was the model but it was not inheritting BaseModel (please excuse the poor naming convention).  As soon as I added the inheritance it worked.

Comment: (Sorry, I was up until 2AM working on this approach and I didn't get much sleep after)

Comment: Btw @seairth if you want to post an answer instead of a comment along the lines of AddToCartResponse possibly not being of type BaseModel I can mark it as the correct answer and close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error information in the comments above indicate that `AddToCartResponse` is not derived from `BaseModel`.

Comment: Thanks again, sir... 'tis what I get for staying up so late!